# How to delete a particular row in Node.js and express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

How can I delete data from a list in Node.js, using `express` and `ejs` view? I have tried, but it's not working. I am using `mongodb`.

Here is what I have done so far but it's not working.

```
router.post('/delete', function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.body.id;

  mongodb.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);

    db.collection('profile').deleteOne({ "_id": objectId(id) }, function(err, result) {
      console.log('Item deleted');
      db.close();
    });
  });

  res.redirect('/userlist');
});
```

and ejs (view) code is:

```
<td><a href="/userlist/delete">Delete</a></td>
```

below code is works but when I press **Delete**, it deletes all the row. Here I used **get** intead of post

```
router.get('/delete', function(req, res, next) {

  mongodb.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);

    db.collection('profile').deleteOne(function(err, result) {
      console.log('Item deleted');
      db.close();
    });
  });

  res.redirect('/userlist');
});
```

Comment: no its proper bcoz i am calling **/delete** from **userlist** page inside that /delete router. The page is **userlist**. inside that i created **/insert, /edit and /delete** router

Comment: Now I added some code. please look into that. if I use get, then it deletes all the row.

Comment: ok! how to do you send post request by `a href ` tag? its not possible so then `req.body` is `undefined`

Comment: Well @farhadamjady is right. You need a call your back-end API's with Ajax or fetch like library  other-wise you not be able to hit back-end server

Comment: can u guys please show me how.. please give me some code..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a get request, it can be done like this:

```
router.get('/delete/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.params.id;

  mongodb.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);

    db.collection('profile').deleteOne({ "_id": objectId(id) }, function(err, result) {
      console.log('Item deleted');
      db.close();
    });
  });

  res.redirect('/userlist');
});
```

Now you need to request something like this:

`<td><a href="/userlist/delete/some-id">Delete</a></td>`